# Webpack babel-loader not parsing arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am adding some react to an existing website and am trying to set up webpack and babel. Webpack works correctly when I don't try to include arrow functions or spread. When I do try to include those, I get an "unexpected token" error. I have searched for hours, so any help with this would be great. I am on Windows.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        homeRefine: [path.join(__dirname, './js/react/src/home-refine.js')]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './js/react/dist')
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blank",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.7",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pack": "webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.config.js",
    "production": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js"
  }
}
```

**HomeSearchRefine.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class HomeSearchRefine extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            arkona: "cag"
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetchCars(this.state.arkona);
    }

    fetchCars = (arkona) => {
        console.log(arkona);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="search-filters">
                <p>Hello world</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HomeSearchRefine;
```

**terminal output**

```
C:\dev\websites\choice\Choice (homepage-react) (choice@1.0.0)
λ npm run pack

> choice@1.0.0 pack C:\dev\websites\choice\Choice
> webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js

Hash: 6dca2e265a78f9c74bb5
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 2493ms
               Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
homeRefine.bundle.js  740 kB       0  [emitted]  homeRefine
   [0] multi homeRefine 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 179 hidden modules

ERROR in ./js/react/src/components/HomeSearchRefine.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/dev/websites/choice/Choice/js/react/src/components/HomeSearchRefine.js: Unexpected token (15:11)

  13 |  }
  14 |
> 15 |  fetchCars = (arkona) => {
     |            ^
  16 |          console.log(arkona);
  17 |  };
  18 |

 @ ./js/react/src/home-refine.js 9:24-64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ES2015 only support class *methods*, not class *properties*. So:

```
class SomeClass {
  // these are valid:
  instanceMethod() { }
  static classMethod() { }

  // these are not valid:
  someProperty = 3;
  invalidMethod = () => { }
  alsoInvalidMethod = function() { }
}
```

If you want to enable this feature (which is [not yet standard](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields)), you should add the [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin to your Babel configuration.

<s>As a side note, note that when using arrow functions in classes in this way, `this` inside that arrow function won't refer to an instance of the class, but—as with all other arrow functions—the `this` value of the parent scope.</s> *(As @loganfsmyth commented, this is not the case for class properties.)*

Comment: Your comment about the `this` in the arrow function is incorrect, with the way class properties are specced, they do have access to the instance.

Comment: @psnoonan Is this the accepted answer? I am trying to find a solution to a similar problem where jsx is not recognised.

Answer (score -1):

define `fetchCars` in your component like this

```
fetchCars(arkona) {
  console.log(arkona);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use an arrow function, and this is a regular function.